# Landing Page Error when using do - while loop: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I wanted to test the script below in Landing page but I am getting the following error:

> **startIndex cannot be larger than length of string**

Any suggestions why this error occurs and how to fix it? By removing do - while loop the page will load just fine so I assume it something to do with it.

**This is my code:**

```javascript
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

  var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
  Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[489FCA33-8204-4A2F-A7D6-8B59F3963EB2]");
  Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Email_Address");

  do {

    var results = [0,0];
    var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
    var status = results[0];
    var requestId = results[1];
    Write("<br>status: " + status);
    Write("<br>requestId: " + requestId);

    if (rows != null) {

       Write("<br>rows.length: " + rows.length);

       for (var i in rows) {
         Write("<br>i:" + i + " " + rows[i].Properties[0].Value);
       }

    }
    rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;

  } while (status == "MoreDataAvailable")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon (;) at the end of while loop. It works.